# Django ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/chat//'

Tags: python, django, redis, routes, chat

I'm working on making a simple chat app using [this tutorial from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrKKRRC518Y) (github link here: [LINK](https://github.com/justdjango/justchat)). One potential issue is that the tutorial uses 2.x version of django but i have 3.1.7, but I had it working pretty well and was close, but then started getting this error:

`ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/chat//'`

When looking at my terminal, it keeps trying to reconnect over and over, possible becaues I'm using the [ReconnectingWebSocket github javascript code](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket). When I run redis-cli and type 'ping', I get 'PONG' in return so I think that is working properly.

**Below is my code:**

**routing.py (I believe this seems most likely where the issue is)**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()), #new django
]
```

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**settings.py:**

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.asgi.application' # older version of django: 'django_project.routing.application'
# Channels redis config:
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

**views.py:**

```
# chat/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/index.html')


@login_required
def room(request, room_name):
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        'room_name_json': room_name
    })
```

**urls.py**
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

```
app_name = 'chat'

urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('chat/<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
]
```

**room.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="{% static '/reconnecting_websockets.js' %}"></script>
    <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br>
    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100"><br>
    <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send">
    {{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
    <script>
        const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

        const chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/chat/'
            + roomName
            + '/'
        );

        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (data.message + '\n'); //grabbing the textarea with id(#) 'chat-log'
        };

        chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
                document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
            }
        };

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
            const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
            const message = messageInputDom.value;
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': message,
                'command': 'fetch_messages'
            }));
            messageInputDom.value = ''; //reset value to empty string
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**consumers.py:**

```
# chat/consumers.py
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from .models import Message
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def fetch_messages(self, data):
        messages = Message.last_10_messages(self)
        content = {
            'command': 'messages',
            'messages': self.messages_to_json(messages)
        }
        self.send_message(content)


    def new_message(self, data):
        author_user = User.objects.filter(username='admin')[0]
        message = Message.objects.create(author=author_user, content=data['message'])
        content = {
            'command': 'new_message',
            'message': self.message_to_json(message)
        }
        return self.send_chat_message(content)


    def messages_to_json(self, messages):
        result = []
        for message in messages:
            result.append(self.message_to_json(message))
        return result

    def message_to_json(self, message):
        return {
            'author': message.author.username,
            'content': message.content,
            'timestamp': str(message.timestamp)
        }

    commands = {
        'fetch_messages': fetch_messages,
        'new_message': new_message
    }


    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        self.commands[data['command']](self, data) # either fetch_messages or new_message

    def send_chat_message(self, message):
        print('in send_chat_message')
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)( # Send message to room group
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    def send_message(self, message):
        print('message: ' + str(message))
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        content1 = message['message']
        content2 = content1['content']
        #self.send(text_data=json.dumps(content2)) # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(content2)) # Send message to WebSocket
```

Comment: can you show the code in your asgi.py

Comment: @seif I found the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution: When i changed views.py to this, it worked:

```
@login_required
def room(request, room_name):
    print('~~~DEBUG~~~')
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        'room_name': room_name
```