# Django channels messaging app: Message not sending to websocket

Tags: python, django, websocket, chat, django-channels

I have completed [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrKKRRC518Y) ([github link to code](https://github.com/justdjango/justchat)) on how to use channels and redis in Django(v. 3.1.7) to make an instant chat app. I did change a couple things from the tutorial, because he is on a different Django version. The error I get when I use his code is explained in [this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743785/django-valueerror-no-route-found-for-path-ws-chat).

I have messages saving to the database and I am successfully loading the 10 most recent messages on page load. But When I click the "send" button, I do not see the message show up in the list of messages (but it does save to the database). When I run `redis-cli` and type 'ping', I get 'PONG' in return so I think redis is working properly.

When I click send, there are no javascript errors in the dev console and no python errors. It just does not show for me (or for a different logged in user who is in the same room).

**~~~UPDATAE~~~**
I believe the problem is in my room.html file, because when i use [the html file from the tutorial](https://github.com/justdjango/justchat/blob/4eb38c748f77b51ffcde8684dfea173af2e33e7b/src/chat/templates/chat/room.html), the web server does not crash ([as indicated in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743785/django-valueerror-no-route-found-for-path-ws-chat)). The main difference between the code from the tutorial and my code here is views.py and room.html.

**Screenshot of front end:**

[image: Screenshot of front end]

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/index.html')


@login_required
def room(request, room_name): # OLD: WORKING (Mar 22, 6pm)
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        'room_name': room_name
    })
```

**routing.py:**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()), #new django
]
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'chat'

urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('chat/<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
]
```

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
# from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone


    class Message(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        content = models.TextField()
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) #todo: timezone fix?
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.author.username
    
        def last_10_messages(self):
            return Message.objects.order_by('-timestamp').all()[:10] # only load last 10 msgs from DB
```

**room.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="{% static '/reconnecting_websockets.js' %}"></script>
    <div id="chat-log"></div>
    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100"><br>
    <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send">


    {{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
    <script>
        const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent); //TODO: check
        var username = "{{ user }}";

        const chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/chat/'
            + roomName
            + '/'
        );

        chatSocket.onopen = function(e) {
            fetchMessages();
        }

        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

            if(data['messages'] != null) {
                var messages = data['messages'];

                for(i=messages.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    var singleMessage = messages[i];
                    createMessage(singleMessage);
                }
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById('chat-log').innerHtml += data; //THIS DOES NOT WORK. But even if this did work i'm not sure it would be using a websocket
            }
        };

        function fetchMessages() {
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({'command': 'fetch_messages' }));
        }

        function createMessage(data) { //this function works, messages in the database are successfully displaying on the page
            var author = data['author'];
            var message = data['content'];
            document.getElementById('chat-log').innerHTML += '<b>' + author + '</b>: ' + message + '<br />';
        }

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
                document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
            }
        };

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
            const messageInputDom = document.getElementById('chat-message-input');
            const message = messageInputDom.value;
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ //This is what we send into the socket
                'command': 'new_message',
                'message': message,
                'from': username
            }));

            messageInputDom.value = ''; //reset value to empty string
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** It turns out this was a dumb mistake by me. I modified the code near the bottom of consumers.py, so i was sort of in-between using the code from the tutorial, and my own code. This now works!!